# How to make a field compulsory to fill before a record can be saved in a bound form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a bound form that adds to an exisitng record when the fields are filled but there are two fields that are very important to be filled.  I want the form to prompt the user to fill those fields before they can be saved if left blank. I can definitely do this in unbound form but I dont know how to implement it in a bound form .

Any input would be greately appreciated

Comment: Please don't shout.

Comment: I dont understand what you meant by this

Comment: Your initial heading was all in caps - I've switched the case.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the field's properties in the table design?

Comment: Yes, I changed the fields' properties to required. but while testing, i intentionally left one of the fields blank and i got a prompt that asked if I wanted to close the atabase object anyway, then  i selected no but it brought another propmt with a header 'Macro single step' , i could close it and add the required field but i dont want this propmt as it could confuse the the user who doesnt know anything about access

Answer (score 0):

Use the *BeforeUpdate* event of the form:

```vb
Cancel = IsNull(Me!SomeField.Value) Or IsNull(Me!SomeOtherField.Value)

If Cancel = True Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in all required values."
End If
```

Comment: it showed the message but if i then click ok, it still brought the propmt you "you cant save at this time". for me its not a problem and I can do it. I am only worried for the inexperienced users

Comment: It depends on the context. You may have to use the `BeforeUpdate` event of each field instead. `Me.Undo` and/or `Me.CancelEvent` may be used, but if a field is required, that kicks in first.

Comment: @firmphem - Have you [turned off the prompts for action queries](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/turn-delete-object-and-action-query-confirmation-messages-on-or-off-e58e4bba-9d54-4b9d-b962-9eca048e5335) in the settings?